# Vue - built-in way to copy query params

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Does Vue have a built-in way to pass over query params between URLs? Or what is an efficient way?

In our components we are using `computed`:

```
computed: {
      queryParams() {
        return this.$route.query
      }
    }
```

and then in `<template>` we use:

```
<router-link :to="{
   name: 'xxx', 
   query: queryParams
}">
```

Comment: you don't need to put it in a computed. you can just use `$route.query` in router link

Comment: @JacobGoh good hint. What if you wanted to merge or dissociate a key from query? Would you write it directly to `<router-link>`?

Comment: no. I would use computed in this case, in order to avoid messy code in template